# mongodb shardCollection gives operation timeout

Tags: mongodb

I was trying to shard a 235 GB collection, But it gives giving the following error:

```
sh.shardCollection("Cake.Clickprime",{"click_date":1})
{ "code" : 50, "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "Operation timed out" }
```

Any help please, as why is this happening?

Comment: I hit the same problem. Any insights what might cause this?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, but if you are still stuck, there might be a shard which is not connecting with the config server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had the same problem sharding a huge collection. We found out that shards and mongos/config had a different mongo version.

Updating all of them to version 3.2.6+ fixed the problem.